# Does throwing an exception within a method cause the method to return?

Tags: c#, exception, methods, return

I have the following code:

```
public static Point operator /(Point point, double value)
    {
        if (value == 0)
        {
            throw new DivideByZeroException("Cannot divide by zero");
            return Point.Origin;
        }
        return new Point(point.X / value, point.Y / value, point.Z / value);
    }
```

And the first return statement (`return Point.Origin;`) is underlined in green in Visual Studio. The message says "Unreachable code detected" when the cursor is hovered over the underlined text. This leads me to my question stated in the title line:

Does throwing an exception within a method cause the method to return?

Comment: Thanks, I understand now: Throwing an exception within a method causes the flow of execution of the program to either go to an appropriate exception handler in the method, (such as a catch or finally statement) if there is one, or to exit the method and go up the call stack until it is handled. In any case, the other code in the method after the `throw new Exception` and outside any catch/finally blocks will never be executed. And to clarify and answer the question, the method does not return a value, but it does "return" in the sense that the program execution returns to the calling method.

Answer (score 11):

Well, it causes the execution of the method to *exit*, yes. The exception is thrown up the stack, to the closest method which catches it. If it didn't affect execution flow, it would be pretty pointless.

This isn't the same as the method returning "normally" - i.e. without an exception. So suppose the calling method had:

```
Point foo = bar / baz;
Console.WriteLine("Done");
```

In this case the `Console.WriteLine()` call *wouldn't* execute if the division operator threw an exception. Instead, *either* the exception would be caught in this method, *or* the exception would propagate to that method's caller, etc.

(`finally` blocks will be executed along the way too.)

It's probably worth reading the MSDN guide to ["handling and throwing exceptions"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5b2yeyab.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

No, because throwing an exception is **not** a return.

If the exception is not handled inside the function it will cause an immediate exit out of the function, passing control to the first point in the program where the exception will be catched ie handled.  (Resulting in a sudden death of the program if it doesn't get handled.)

Since the function will exit after the throw the return statement is useless as it will never be reached.,

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly.  When an exception is thrown, if caught, it will jump to the handling code within the method.  From there it can do whatever you'd like.  If uncaught as in your example, it will jump to the method that called this method and will never "return" a value.  It will also never return to execute the return line you have after your thrown exception.

Answer (score 1):

> Does throwing an exception within a method cause the method to return?

Yes. Execution of a method is being interrupted, so method returns it execution flow. But no value is returned you defined it with `return` statement. No line after `throw new` in current method is being executed, except of corresponding `catch` and `finally` blocks. So you don't have to return values after throwing an exception.

Visual Studio underlines blocks of code, which it detected cannot be reached. In your specific case  `return Point.Origin;` statement is never going to be executed, so you can remove it.

Comment: Is it really a `return` like behavior? Because technically the function doesn't return a value but it signals an exception. Am I wrong?

Comment: You are right. We are speaking about return of execution flow, not returned values. `cause the method to return` can be treated as `cause  to return execution flow` or `cause to return value`: first if true, second is false.

Comment: @cheesemacfly - an Exception _aborts_ the method, making returning a value a non-issue.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I do agree but the question was asking if it causes the method to return. So still not sure if it's a yes or a no. (But I guess it is more a problem of word meaning than anything else)

Comment: It certainly does not return (a value) in the normal way.

Comment: @IlyaIvanov - but _not_ to the callsite... Exceptions introduce an entirely separate control-flow in terms of `finally` and `catch` blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, throwing an exception causes the method to return immediately.

However, it's not a normal return. For example, there is no return value. The only way to capture control from a method that is returning as a result of an exception being thrown, is to have an exception handler.